# How can I draw a line after each row inside the section full across the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core

I have a section 'current projects', I would like to draw a line after each project. The horizontal rule is not working to draw the line across the page under each project starts.
Here is  the code attached

```html
<section>
  <div class=" container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-1  py-4 text-center" style=" background: #2b2b2b;">
        <h3>Current Projects</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p style="text-align: justify;"> Quisque pellentesque dolor in ante rhoncus hendrerit. Aenean luctus elit et enim bibendum facilisis. Quisque sed sem sodales, pellentesque metus ut, sodales enim. Cras mi arcu, egestas vitae velit nec, condimentum semper lectus. Nunc eget
                tortor nunc. Quisque sodales pellentesque dui sed cursus. Phasellus in dictum nunc. Curabitur in ullamcorper lacus, et fringilla tortor. Nam magna eros, volutpat vel gravida imperdiet, egestas a neque. Donec mattis dui quis mi accumsan consequat. Duis fringilla eleifend ante, hendrerit pretium felis iaculis sit amet. Aliquam bibendum, mi quis faucibus varius, sem ex accumsan ante, at blandit sapien ante at velit. Donec commodo vestibulum orci suscipit pellentesque. Sedornare enim et orci vestibulum tincidunt.</p>
  <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/car-german-2.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="row"> // Here I have to draw a line..
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p style="text-align: justify;"> Fusce blandit consequat auctor. Cras at est a dui ullamcorper semper. Aliquam faucibus bibendum est ut accumsan. Nullam varius tincidunt urna, eu facilisis eros aliquet a. In placerat facilisis neque vitae porta. Donec congue laoreet enimsit amet bibendum. Pellentesque dapibus eget sem eu aliquam. Etiam suscipit suscipit placerat. Sed ultrices nibh dui, in tristique tortor aliquam ultrices. Nam eleifend lorem dui, a viverra mi placerat in. In vehicula eget mi non condimentum.Aliquam quis congue urna, sed maximus sapien. </p>
              <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/laptop.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why not `.row { border-bottom: solid 2px #000 }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-bottom` property on each row nested inside a column (according to your html structure)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8zfhna25/

```css
.col-md-12 .row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class=" container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-1  py-4 text-center" style=" background: #2b2b2b;">
        <h3>Current Projects</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p style="text-align: justify;"> Quisque pellentesque dolor in ante rhoncus hendrerit. Aenean luctus elit et enim bibendum facilisis. Quisque sed sem sodales, pellentesque metus ut, sodales enim. Cras mi arcu, egestas vitae velit nec, condimentum semper lectus. Nunc eget
                tortor nunc. Quisque sodales pellentesque dui sed cursus. Phasellus in dictum nunc. Curabitur in ullamcorper lacus, et fringilla tortor. Nam magna eros, volutpat vel gravida imperdiet, egestas a neque. Donec mattis dui quis mi accumsan consequat. Duis fringilla eleifend ante, hendrerit pretium felis iaculis sit amet. Aliquam bibendum, mi quis faucibus varius, sem ex accumsan ante, at blandit sapien ante at velit. Donec commodo vestibulum orci suscipit pellentesque. Sedornare enim et orci vestibulum tincidunt.</p>
              <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/car-german-2.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="row"> // Here I have to draw a line..
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p style="text-align: justify;"> Fusce blandit consequat auctor. Cras at est a dui ullamcorper semper. Aliquam faucibus bibendum est ut accumsan. Nullam varius tincidunt urna, eu facilisis eros aliquet a. In placerat facilisis neque vitae porta. Donec congue laoreet enimsit amet bibendum. Pellentesque dapibus eget sem eu aliquam. Etiam suscipit suscipit placerat. Sed ultrices nibh dui, in tristique tortor aliquam ultrices. Nam eleifend lorem dui, a viverra mi placerat in. In vehicula eget mi non condimentum.Aliquam quis congue urna, sed maximus sapien. </p>
              <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/laptop.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

js, you can do it like this or use border-bottom css

```html
<section>
  <div class=" container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-1  py-4 text-center" style=" background: #2b2b2b;">
        <h3>Current Projects</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p style="text-align: justify;"> Quisque pellentesque dolor in ante rhoncus hendrerit. Aenean luctus elit et enim bibendum facilisis. Quisque sed sem sodales, pellentesque metus ut, sodales enim. Cras mi arcu, egestas vitae velit nec, condimentum semper lectus. Nunc eget
                tortor nunc. Quisque sodales pellentesque dui sed cursus. Phasellus in dictum nunc. Curabitur in ullamcorper lacus, et fringilla tortor. Nam magna eros, volutpat vel gravida imperdiet, egestas a neque. Donec mattis dui quis mi accumsan consequat. Duis fringilla eleifend ante, hendrerit pretium felis iaculis sit amet. Aliquam bibendum, mi quis faucibus varius, sem ex accumsan ante, at blandit sapien ante at velit. Donec commodo vestibulum orci suscipit pellentesque. Sedornare enim et orci vestibulum tincidunt.</p>
  <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/car-german-2.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div>
          <div class="row"> // Here I have to draw a line..
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p style="text-align: justify;"> Fusce blandit consequat auctor. Cras at est a dui ullamcorper semper. Aliquam faucibus bibendum est ut accumsan. Nullam varius tincidunt urna, eu facilisis eros aliquet a. In placerat facilisis neque vitae porta. Donec congue laoreet enimsit amet bibendum. Pellentesque dapibus eget sem eu aliquam. Etiam suscipit suscipit placerat. Sed ultrices nibh dui, in tristique tortor aliquam ultrices. Nam eleifend lorem dui, a viverra mi placerat in. In vehicula eget mi non condimentum.Aliquam quis congue urna, sed maximus sapien. </p>
              <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/laptop.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

use `<hr>`tag

or

use border-bottom style for each section

Comment: _"Horizontal rule is not working to draw the line across the page under each projects starts"_